# Click on img with locateCenterOnScreen with pyAutoGui

Tags: python, error-handling, pyautogui

I'm trying to press on File with pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen with an image (file.png), but I keep getting an unknown error from my point of view that I can't fix.

Code:

```
import pyautogui

cord = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("file.png")
pyautogui.click(cord)
```

Error:

```
PS D:\pressFile> & "C:/Python Software/Python3_12_2/python.exe" d:/pressFile/pressFile.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\pressFile\pressFile.py", line 3, in <module>
    cord = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("file.png")
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: couldNotImportPyScreeze() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
PS D:\pressFile>
```

Version:

```
Python 3.12.2
```

```
Requirement already satisfied: pyautogui in c:\python software\python3_12_2\lib\site-packages (0.9.41)
Requirement already satisfied: pymsgbox in c:\python software\python3_12_2\lib\site-packages (from pyautogui) (1.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: PyTweening>=1.0.1 in c:\python software\python3_12_2\lib\site-packages (from pyautogui) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in c:\python software\python3_12_2\lib\site-packages (from pyautogui) (10.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyscreeze in c:\python software\python3_12_2\lib\site-packages (from pyautogui) (0.1.30)
Requirement already satisfied: pygetwindow in c:\python software\python3_12_2\lib\site-packages (from pyautogui) (0.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: pyrect in c:\python software\python3_12_2\lib\site-packages (from pygetwindow->pyautogui) (0.2.0)
```

Screenshot:
[Image with code + error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dd3vX.png)

1. Reinstall everything
2. Watch different tutorials

What I expected it to do.. well work?

Comment: error shows `"couldNotImportPyScreeze"` - and this can be the problem. As I know `pyautogui` uses module [PyScreeze](https://github.com/asweigart/pyscreeze) (created by the same author) and this module uses external programs (created in C/C++) like `screencapture` (on MacOS), `scrot` (on Linux) and you have to install them separatelly.

Comment: these can other problem. You use the newest `Python 3.12` but some modules may not be ready to work with newest Python - authors may need some time to create correct version - so it is good to use little older version (like `Python 3.11`). Or you should keep two versions `3.11` and `3.12` and check which one works for your. I have even 4 versions on Linux - 3.9, 3.10, 3.11, 3.12 - but I still use `3.10` as main version. I can run them using command `python3.9`, `python3.10`, `python3.11`, `python3.12` and the same for `pip` - `pip3.9`, `pip3.10`, `pip3.11`, `pip3.12`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Changing the Python version from 3.12 to 3.11 worked like a charm!
Now I can get back to work on my program, thanks Furas!